# Where should I put "free(BlockOfMemory)" in this code?

Tags: c, malloc, free, sizeof, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *numbers = malloc(5 * sizeof(int)); 
    // Speicherplatz auf 10 ints vergrößern
    int *temp = realloc(numbers, 10 * sizeof(int));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        numbers = temp;
        printf("Speicher erfolgreich vergrößert.\n");
    } else {
        // Fehlerbehandlung
        printf("Speicher konnte nicht vergrößert werden.\n");
        free(numbers);
        return 1;
    }
    free(numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to expand my storage from 5 integers to 10 integers just for practice. I don't know where to put the call "`free(numbers)`".

Comment: You call `free` when you're done with the memory that was give to you by `malloc` (or `realloc`, or `calloc`), when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing it correctly as you are doing it right now. If `realloc` relocates the data (indicated by `realloc` returning a pointer that is not equal to `numbers`) it will automatically `free(numbers)`, so no matter how many times you call `realloc`, you should only call `free` once, just like you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly reorganized, your code could read like this.  It has a single call to `free()`, which is somewhat beneficial.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *numbers = malloc(5 * sizeof(int)); 
    int *temp = realloc(numbers, 10 * sizeof(int));
    int  rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    if (temp != NULL) {
        numbers = temp;    // Reassign numbers to point to the new data
        printf("Speicher erfolgreich vergrößert.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Speicher konnte nicht vergrößert werden.\n");
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // If realloc succeeded, free the new value.
    // If realloc failed, free the old value.
    free(numbers);

    return rc;
}
```

Once you call `realloc(numbers, new_size)` and it returns a non-null pointer in `temp`, you should not try to use the value originally stored in `numbers` again. Only if `realloc()` returns a null pointer should you invoke `free(numbers)`.  Your code copies the new pointer over the old when the allocation is successful, so you don't (ab)use the old value.

Your code, therefore, is correct.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for this great and detailed answer. I forgot that I asked this question but now I read it and you exactly said what I needed.